# Getting HRESULT E_FAIL when trying to call a method in AS3 from C#

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, com-interop

I am getting the `HRESULT E_FAIL` error when trying to access a method in an AS3 .swf file, running as an AxShockwaveFlashObject component inside a Winform.
The flash component can communicate with C# through Externalinterface just fine, but sendin from C# to Flash has been impossible so far.

The error seems to be generic and meaningless, as I've found lots of unanswered questions. I will try nevertheless for this specific scenario:

**C#**

```
String method = "<invoke name=\"NewFilename\" returntype=\"xml\"></invoke><arguments></arguments>";
mainFlashControl.CallFunction(method);
```

**AS3**

```
public function Main():void 
{
    if (stage) init();
    else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void 
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    if (ExternalInterface.available)
    {
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("NewFilename", NewFilename);
    }   
}

public function NewFilename():void
{
    // Do Something...
}
```

UPDATE: All I've [been able to find](http://forums.adobe.com/message/84670?tstart=0#84670) is a workaround that checks every time interval for any function waiting to be called, by making a call (from AS3 to C#) and reading the response. However, I also can't get the response to return anything. I've used `flashComponent.setResponseValue("test");` and on the flash side the Externalinterface.Call() always returns null.

UPDATE: I've also looked into FSCommand now, also works form AS3 to C# but there doesn't seem to be any way for me to attach a return value to it either...

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but are you sure `addCallback` is actually being executed?

Comment: yes. (Through a small hack: after the addCallback, within the if statement, I printed some text on the screen and it appeared)

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work. I guess it needed an argument to work:

**C#**

```
        String method = "<invoke name=\"NewFilename\" returntype=\"xml\"><arguments><string>"+sfd.FileName+"</string></arguments></invoke>";
        mainFlashControl.CallFunction(method);
```

**AS3**

```
    public function Main():void 
    {
        if (stage) init();
        else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    }

    private function init(e:Event = null):void 
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        _mainState = new MainState();
        addChild(_mainState);
        _editState = new EditState();
        addChild(_editState);
        _selectKeyState = new SelectKeyState();
        addChild(_selectKeyState);

        if (ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            ExternalInterface.addCallback ("NewFilename",NewFilename);
        }   
    }


    public function NewFilename(s:String):Boolean
    {
        _mainState.visible = false;
        var th:TextHandle = new TextHandle(s, 100);
        th.y = 200;
        this.addChild(th);
        return true;
    }
```